# Especificar zona horaria en salidas del log

Tags: java, kotlin, logger

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Kotlin y Spring y me ha surgido una duda con un log y la zona horaria usada. Utilizamos [LoggerFactory](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html) para escribir en la salida estándar información sobre los eventos (un log de eventos) pero la hora que muestra no es la adecuada.

Éste es el código (reducido y *pseudo-codificado* en algunas partes) de mi clase principal:

```
package com.micompania.midepartamento.miproyecto

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
// otros imports

@SpringBootApplication
// otras anotaciones
open class miApplication {
  companion object {
    // algunas cosas por aquí
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(miApplication::class.java)
      log.info("Arrancando ${miApplication::class.simpleName} ...")
      // más cosas por acá
      SpringApplication.run(miApplication::class.java, *args)
    }
  }
}
```

Esto funciona sin problemas, y en la salida estándar veo algo como:

> 2018-01-31 11:22:32.542 [main] INFO com.micompania.midepartamento.miproyecto.miApplication - Arrancando MiApplication ...

Lo cual es correcto. Pero hay un problema: la hora que aparece es la hora local de la máquina en la que corre el proyecto, y para evitar confusiones queremos que todas las horas sean en UTC. ¿Hay alguna manera de indicarle al logger que use la zona horaria UTC? ¿Cómo sería?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que usé al final fue cambiar la zona horaria de la aplicación (y no sólo del logger) para que las fechas y horas fueran en UTC. Esto se puede hacer así:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

Como precaución, verifique que la zona horaria no se modificara en ninguna otra parte del proyecto. Y al final, el código de la clase principal quedó así:

```
package com.micompania.midepartamento.miproyecto

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.util.TimeZone
// otros imports

@SpringBootApplication
// otras anotaciones
open class miApplication {
  companion object {
    // algunas cosas por aquí
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      // especificar zona horaria UTC para el log
      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
      val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(miApplication::class.java)
      log.info("Arrancando ${miApplication::class.simpleName} ...")
      // más cosas por acá
      SpringApplication.run(miApplication::class.java, *args)
    }
  }
}
```